# Rotating a 3D plot constantly resizes

Tags: plotting, visualization

When I click and drag a 3D plot it rotates and when I release the mouse, the size of the image changes. This is distracting to me, I'd much rather have it look the same when I release the mouse button

Edit: Spherical region has improved it quite a bit but there is still some resizing:

While holding down

[image]

When I release

[image]

Comment: Have a look at the option `SphericalRegion`.

Comment: Still moves around.

Comment: You did set it to `True`, didn't you? Why not post the thing you have trouble with… oh, and look at `RotationAction` too.

Comment: Edited the original post

Comment: RotationAction fixes the resize problem completely, but it clips the axis numbers. I guess that's the price to pay.

Comment: `SphericalRegion->True` and `RotationAction->"Clip"` seem redundant, choose the one or the other. To avoid the clipping you can just zoom out or add some padding around the image for example with option `ImagePadding->20`

Answer (score 2):

```
Plot3D[Sin[x + y^2], {x, -3, 3} , {y, -2, 2}, SphericalRegion->True, RotationAction -> "Clip"]
```

Comment: The answer, while technically correct, is not the best response -- all of the suggestions in the answer are coming from the comments.